# Dockerized Spring Boot on AWS Beanstalk not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Spring boot app to AWS Beanstalk through Github action but it is not accessible. Set up Spring boot to run on port 5000 and exposed it because from my understanding beanstalk open the port 5000. Watching the AWS logs I see that Spring boot correctly starts at port 5000. Below my configuration files:

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD /target/demoCI-CD-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 5000
```

This is the link not working: http://dockerreact-env.eba-v2y3spbp.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com/test

Answer (score 0):

Having a docker-compose.yml in the project beanstalk takes it in consideration and there was the issue with port mapping. Below the correct map porting in docker-composer.yml.

```
version: "3"
services:
web:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
ports:
  - "80:8080"
```